# Is there any solution to make this kind of table layout in android through XML?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to make a table having 4 columns and 7 rows but the first column has 0 rows against it. Is there any XML solution to this table? I am attaching my table picture which I need to make.

[image: This is the table I am trying to make]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code has worked for me and made exactly what I wanted.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:rotation="-90"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Lunch">

                    </TextView>

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Diet">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Quantity">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Image">

                    </TextView>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Diet">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Quantity">

                    </TextView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                    </ImageView>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Diet">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Quantity">

                    </TextView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                    </ImageView>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Diet">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Quantity">

                    </TextView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                    </ImageView>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Diet">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Quantity">

                    </TextView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                    </ImageView>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Diet">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Quantity">

                    </TextView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                    </ImageView>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Diet">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Quantity">

                    </TextView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                    </ImageView>

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make:

1. A 3 column 7 rows table
2. and a textView at the left of table

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView"

   android:layout_width="match_parent"

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   android:text="Lunch"
   **android:rotation="-90"**/>

Comment: You don't have the corner Cell if that is important or not, also probably better to use a `constraintlayout` as the parent, then you can constrain the `Textview` to the top and bottom of the table otherwise the rotated `Textview` might not align with the table.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew to add more explaination.